# How to link to page inside a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

When I click on the link I created on the website; If the application is installed, I want it to open and go to the page I want in the application, if the application is not installed, I want it to go to the app store or play store. I searched a lot but couldn't find it. Can you help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFgtm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for you would be `deep linking` or `custom scheme`. Them are practically, the same thing. Here you can find a link how to use them:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283

Comment: I tried that and couldn't, the codes in this article are outdated. I want to do both android and ios. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work on the emulator. I tried it on real phone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Firebase Dynamic links was created for.

You can configure urls to redirect based on whether the user has the app installed or not.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: we want to do without firebase. Thanks